# Can't see file contents of GitHub repo in Firefox

Tags: github, firefox

Whenever I click on a file in a GitHub repo in my web browser to view its contents, I just see a blank screen:

[Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQgLB.png)

When I try this on a different browser, say Edge, it works totally fine:

[Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHfRj.png)

I've tried clearing my cache by "forgetting" about the site, but that doesn't change anything. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm having the same issues. For some reason, files within Github repos are not showing.  I did the same test as @ShashComandur, and was able to see files in Edge but not Firefox. Not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get Firefox to show the Github repo files by turning off all my Firefox browser extensions, as is noted in this [Firefox help comment](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1379669).